# Why std::get_deleter() always yields nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I've trying to use c++14 and wonder why std::get_deleter never return a pointer that it should do. Here is the code, please tell me someone why it's output is 0:

https://ideone.com/WT5uSR

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> iptr(new int(999), [](int*p){delete(p);});
    auto _d = std::get_deleter<void(*)(int*)>(iptr);

    if(_d)
        std::cout<<"1";
    else
        std::cout<<"0";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `get_deleter` is a type-unerasing function that requires *you* to know what type went in originally. Since the type of a lambda expression is not nominable, you can't do it in the simple fashion you want.

To get a hold of the type, you'll need to bind it to some name somehow. For example:

```
auto my_del = [](int*p){delete(p);};

std::shared_ptr<int> iptr(new int(999), my_del);
```

Now you can say:

```
std::get_deleter<decltype(my_del)>(iptr);
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//               unspellable type of the lambda expression
```

It's important to understand that type erasure doesn't give you magic runtime powers to see whether one thing can act as another thing. This is best demonstrated on a simpler example: an `std::any(5 /* int */)`  cannot be extracted with an `std::any_cast<double>`, even though `int` is convertible to `double`. But that information is not available at runtime.

Comment: +1, or, in this case, you could force conversion to a function pointer by writing `+[](int*p){delete(p);}` and achieve the desired result.

Comment: Yep, seems lambda is the issue. Code without lambda outputs 1 https://ideone.com/mRU3Nj

Comment: Okay, now the trouble is, how to get deleter independently of which type used to pass to constructor of shared_ptr. In my case it could be a lambda or something from a kind of derived class (complete code see here http://ideone.com/GScXXp) :
class MyObjectPtr:public shared_ptr{ 
public:  
MyObjectPtr(T*p):shared_ptr(p, [](T*p){delete p;})
{}
} my_smart_ptr;
auto my_del = get_deleter<???>(my_smart_ptr);

Comment: @DmitryIlukhin: I think what you're asking is fundamentally at odds with the very concept of type erasure.

Comment: @KerrekSB Seems all I need is to save deleter's type somewhere by "typedef" or "using" and pass all iI need to shared_ptr's constructor converted by static_cast